# Porting VC++ SetWaitableTimer to gcc

Tags: linux, visual-c++, gcc, porting

I've legacy code that uses [SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to perform some task at 10 sec after midnight.

`SetWaitableTimer` has the following feature, which is used in the code:

> If the system time is adjusted, the
>   due time of any outstanding absolute
>   timers is adjusted.

I'm porting code to gcc/Linux. How I can simulate the above behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.helsinki.fi/atk/unix/dec_manuals/DOC_40D/APS33DTE/DOCU_007.HTM) is a pretty good overview of linux timer functions.  You want the [`timer_create()` / `timer_delete()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_create) family with `CLOCK_REALTIME`, then [`timer_settime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_settime) with `TIMER_ABSTIME`.  According to [this FAQ](http://juliusdavies.ca/posix_clocks/clock_realtime_linux_faq.html) it should be adjusted if there is a change to the system clock though I have never tested it.